# English sentence in which words are lexicographically ordered

Tags: creative-writing

I'm looking for a nice English sentence in which the words are lexicographically ordered, preferably without repetitions of first letters and as long as possible.

> "At bathtime, Clara demanded eigenvalues for general Hermitians."

Alternatively, a short story.

Comment: Migrated from ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425299/english-sentence-in-which-words-are-lexicographically-ordered

Comment: This sounds more like a puzzle than a question about writing.  It [might be on-topic on Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I don't know if the lack of a single correct answer would disqualify it.

Comment: I think you are thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abecedarius